# ggplot - R - Alluvial charts - More space between bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I made to build this chart with ggalluvial but I couldn't manage to put the labels in a proper way that is not overlapping. Does anyone know what I can do to make it better? I was thinking in make the space between the bars wider but I didn't manage to do it.

[image]

So far I did this:

```
ggplot(data = alluvialTransposedNA,
       aes(x = x, stratum = stratum, alluvium = id,
           y = Freq, fill = Agency, label = stratum)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.2, .2)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Agency), width = 1/6) + 
  geom_stratum(width = 1/3, alpha = 1.5) + +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),size=2) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.75, hjust=1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=mycolors[1:2])))+
  ggtitle("Evolution topics during covid-19")
```

Comment: You can only make the bars further apart if you make the plot bigger or make the bars narrower. It might help to rotate your labels 90 degrees

Comment: Do you need to restrict each label to one line, or would you allow the text to wrap? Do the labels need to stay inside the rectangles, or do they just need to avoid overlapping with each other? And must they be labels (with bubbles) rather than text (without)? (There may be a solution using the ggfittext package, but it would depend on these questions.)